# Unable to find element after adding className in html file

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, cypress

If I am manually adding id , test-id or classname in html file . Here I have added 'Classname' just as an example to show you.

[image]
Cypress is not able to find the element[image]

using cy.get(".todo-list") to locate the button as I have mentioned classname (shown in screenshot).
[image]

Comment: are you using a js framework? react?  Could you add content of "view page source" from your browser?

Comment: @Mate Yes this is angular . I am directly adding attributes on html file so that I can use them in tests. If you need , I can paste the HTML file content.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `class` instead of `className` attribute on the button. For example, `class="todo-list"`.

Some things like JSX in React use `className` due to the  fact that `class` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, but since this is vanilla HTML it isn't necessary. Also, for the future, could you paste the code snippets instead of just screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

@Bryce is correct (assuming it's not a React app), but in general any attribute can be queried using an extended syntax

```js
cy.get('[className="todo-list"]')
```

---

Looking at the [UIKit](https://getuikit.com/docs/avoiding-conflicts) docs,

> By default, all classes and attributes in UIkit start with the uk- prefix. This avoids name collisions when introducing UIkit to existing projects or when combining it with other frameworks.

so maybe add the class prefix `uk-` (although this may just be to avoid conflict in the style sheets and have no bearing on the test).

```html
<button class="uk-todo-list" >
```

```js
cy.get('.todo-list')
```

---

Generally speaking, using a class is less solid than using a `data-cy` attribute, since classes also control styling and may be changed in the future.

Cypress recommends this

```html
<button data-cy="todo-list" >
```

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="todo-list"]')
```

Comment: Looks like you're using [UIKit](https://getuikit.com/docs/introduction), but I can't tell if it treats class attributes the same as React does.

Comment: I also tried using test-id attribute but that dint work in this case.